# unable to get IS NULL values for user_id in MYSQL godaddy

Tags: mysql

I am using MYSQL Database  for back-end server in Godaddy phpMyAdmin, While using it i am unable to get NULL values for user_id when i LEFT JOIN two tables posts table and likes table

MYSQL CODE

```
SELECT P.id, P.description, P.user_id, L.user_id AS likes_user_id, L.like_status 
  FROM posts P LEFT JOIN likes L ON L.post_id=P.id  
  WHERE L.user_id=1 OR  L.user_id IS NULL
  ORDER BY P.id ASC
```

The above mysql query is working fine but i am not getting NULL values in Godaddy shared hosting phpMyAdmin but i am getting NULL values in my localhost .

Getting OUTPUT

```
id   description      user_id     likes_user_id  like_status
1    Good evening      2              1           true
2    Hi good day       2              1           false
3    Hi good morning   1              1           false
4    Good morning      1              1           true
```

Required OUTPUT

```
id   description      user_id     likes_user_id  like_status
1    Good evening      2              1           true
2    Hi good day       2              1           false
3    Hi good morning   1              1           false
4    Good morning      1              1           true
5    Modified bike     1              NULL        NULL
6    Hi good evening   1              NULL        NULL
```

I don't know why i am getting output like this in Godaddy shared hosting phpMyAdmin,

```
WHERE (L.user_id=1 OR  L.user_id IS NULL ) 
WHERE L.user_id=1 OR  L.user_id IS NULL 
WHERE L.user_id=1 OR ISNULL( L.user_id)
```

I tried all the above where clause methods but they are working in localhost but not working in Godaddy phpMyAdmin ,

Please check my code once and help me to solve this *** MYSQL WHERE clause IS NULL condition ***

Comment: `ON L.post_id=P.id  AND (L.user_id=1 OR  L.user_id IS NULL)` and remove the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thank you for the response,  your code changes are  working fine thank you.